# Merging layers in Spline Design

Tags: 3d, spline, react-three-fiber

Is there a way to merge different objects together in the current state of the [spline.design](https://spline.design) web 3D tool?

Boolean merges will result in multiple objects in the resulting code export which is what I'm trying to avoid. In Figma this functionality can be achieved by merging multiple layers using the *Flatten* option.

Could not find any options in the tool and no reference in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

yes! select the layers you want to merge by holding shift and then on the right side panel you'll see "boolean modifier" which should give you the option to merge geometries. heres a link to splines more in depth review of boolean operations: https://docs.spline.design/abc1708f70ad41be88116076d5b916d2

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've tried this, but the geometries will still remain separate in the exported file.